# How to extract hostname and port from URL string?

Tags: regex, scala

I need to extract hostname and port (if any) from an URL and here below is my code:

```
val regEx = """^(?:https?:\/\/)?(?:www\.)?(.*?)\//""".r
val url = regEx.split("http://www.domain.com:8080/one/two")
val hostname = url(url.length - 1).split("/")(0).split(":")(0)
val hasPort = url(url.length - 1).split("/")(0).split(":").length > 1
val port = if (hasPort) url(url.length - 1).split("/")(0).split(":")(1) else 80
```

The code above works as expected... but for sure in Scala there is a better way to get the same result.

How do I get hostname and port (if any) without using all those ugly `split`s?

Comment: Yes... that was the idea... but in this case I think what suggests Gabriele is the best solution. Tx.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Without reinventing the wheel, you can simply leverage `java.net.URL`

```
val url = new java.net.URL("http://www.domain.com:8080/one/two")
val hostname = url.getHost // www.domain.com
val port = url.getPort     // 8080
```

A minor difference, `getPort` returns `-1` if no port is specified, so you have to handle that case explicitly.

```
val port = if (url.getPort == -1) url.getDefaultPort else url.getPort
```

Comment: Note you should use `new java.net.URI` if you have urls like `ws://domain.com:1234` (websockets). `java.net.URL` will throw on the `ws` protocol but `java.net.URI` is fine with it. `java.net.URI` has `getHost` and `getPort` too.